# Quiero que la Macro que diseñe se quede en un solo libro, mientras verifica otro

Tags: vba

Soy nuevo diseñando macros, hice una que verifica un proceso de ventas de unos restaurantes, en donde cuando realiza este proceso va saltando de un libro a otro, quisiera saber si es posible mantenerla en el libro inicial mientras verifica el otro libro, ya que esto genera unos parpadeos en la pantalla de mi equipo, adjunto macro y una breve explicación sobre la misma.

La macro consiste en dos archivos, uno en donde tengo una tabla a llenar con las ventas y otro que se me es entregado diario con las ventas de la noche anterior para generar un informe, al ejecutar la macro "buscar", me pregunta por la ruta del archivo que quiero abrir, esto para identificar el archivo que debo filtrar, en la macro hay unos vectores con los nombres de los productos que debe buscar, luego en ese archivo el encontrara un listado con los productos antes mencionados, el cual debe recorrer mediante un bucle (for-next/loop), al realizar el proceso establecido en el bucle realiza saltos de pantalla desde el primer libro en donde se ejecuta la macro al segundo libro en donde están los productos vendidos, busco corregir los parpadeos.

```
Option Explicit

Sub BUSCAR()

Dim MiArchivo As String

MiArchivo = InputBox("Ingrese direccion de busqueda", "BUSQUEDA DE ARCHIVO")
MiArchivo = Mid(MiArchivo, 2, Len(MiArchivo) - 2)
    If MiArchivo <> "" Then
    Workbooks.Open MiArchivo
    End If

Dim CARTA(44) As String

    CARTA(1) = "AGUA EN BOTELLA SW"
    CARTA(2) = "AGUA BOTELLA FLL SW"
    CARTA(3) = "AGUA BOTE CON GAS SW"
    CARTA(4) = "CERVE AGUILA LIGTH SW"
    CARTA(5) = "MICHE AGUILA LIGTH SW"
    CARTA(6) = "CERVE AGUILA NORMAL SW"
    CARTA(7) = "MICHE AGUILA NORMAL SW"
    CARTA(8) = "CERVE ANDINA SW"
    CARTA(9) = "MICHE ANDINA SW"
    CARTA(10) = "CERVE  BUDWEISER SW"
    CARTA(11) = "MICHE BUDWEISER SW"
    CARTA(12) = "CERVE CLUB COL DORADA SW"
    CARTA(13) = "MICHE CLUB COL DORADA SW"
    CARTA(14) = "CERVE CLUB COL ROJA SW"
    CARTA(15) = "MICHE CLUB COL ROJA SW"
    CARTA(16) = "CERVE ANGELO PORETTI 4 SW"
    CARTA(17) = "MICHE ANGELO PORETTI 4 SW"
    CARTA(18) = "CERVE ANGELO PORETTI 5 SW"
    CARTA(19) = "MICHE ANGELO PORETTI 5 SW"
    CARTA(20) = "CERVE ANGELO PORETTI 6 SW"
    CARTA(21) = "MICHE ANGELO PORETTI 6 SW"
    CARTA(22) = "CERVE CORONA SW"
    CARTA(23) = "MICHE CORONA SW"
    CARTA(24) = "CERVE HEINEKEN SW"
    CARTA(25) = "MICHE HEINEKEN SW"
    CARTA(26) = "CERVE STELLA ARTOIS SW"
    CARTA(27) = "MICHE STELLA ARTOIS SW"
    CARTA(28) = "GS COCA COLA NOR SW"
    CARTA(29) = "GS COCA COLA NOR FLL SW"
    CARTA(30) = "GS COCA COLA ZERO SW"
    CARTA(31) = "GS COCA COLA ZERO FLL SW"
    CARTA(32) = "GS PEPSI SW"
    CARTA(33) = "GS MANZANA SW"
    CARTA(34) = "GS COLOMBIANA SW"
    CARTA(35) = "GS KOLA ROMAN SW"
    CARTA(36) = "GS SPRITE SW"
    CARTA(37) = "GS GINGER SW"
    CARTA(38) = "GS GINGER MICHELA SW"
    CARTA(39) = "SODA SW"
    CARTA(40) = "SODA MICHELADA SW"
    CARTA(41) = "SODA FLL SW"
    CARTA(42) = "GS TONICA SW"
    CARTA(43) = "VB PICOLO SW"
    CARTA(44) = "VT PICOLO SW"


Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 44

Worksheets("VENTAS").Cells(i + 2, 3).Value = sumar(CARTA(i))
Workbooks(2).Activate

Next i
 
End Sub
Function sumar(nombre As String) As Integer

Dim suma As Integer
suma = 0
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
    
Do While ((Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, 1)) <> "")
    If (nombre = Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, 7) And Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, 16) = "BAR SEA WATCH") Then
    suma = suma + Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, 8).Value
    End If

    i = i + 1
Loop
    
Workbooks(1).Activate
sumar = suma

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar los parpadeos, puedes desactivar la actualización de pantalla:

> [Propiedad Application.ScreenUpdating
> (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating)

¡Recuerda reactivarla al finalizar tu código! Se implementa muy fácil:

```
Sub BUSCAR()

Application.ScreenUpdating=False
Dim MiArchivo As String
' resto de tu código
'
'
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, Si funciono, ya había buscado en otra ocasión esta propiedad pero no sabia que me funcionaria, fue de mucha ayuda